# Add regular price before price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Multi-Currency plugin for WooCommerce. The prices are now converted to MKD Denars. Now I want to show a regular price (USD) before price in (MKD).

Here is my code in Function.php

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    $text = 'echo $product->get_regular_price;';

    // returning the text before the price
    return $text . ' ' . $price;
}
```

Can someone help me use the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use echo inside quotes as it is interprated as as common text string.

So your function could look like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );

function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
     global $product;

     // display regular price before the price
     return $product->get_regular_price . ' ' . $price;

}
```

You can also format the price using wc_price() function.